# ColdFusion Equivalent to PHP Unpack and SHA1

Tags: php, coldfusion

Here is my problem. In PHP there are two functions that I am having a hard time replicating in ColdFusion.

1) PHP's unpack function which let's you format the output in a given way. One of the format options is 'H' which stands for "Hex string, high nibble first" - How could I replicate this in ColdFusion?

This is what I have so far...

```
<cfscript>
function stringToBinary( String stringValue ){
    var base64Value = toBase64( stringValue );
    var binaryValue = toBinary( base64Value );
    return( binaryValue );
}

function stringToHex( String stringValue ){
    var binaryValue = stringToBinary( stringValue );
    var hexValue = binaryEncode( binaryValue, "hex" );
    return( lcase( hexValue ) );
}   
</cfscript>
```

So I can't figure out to specify high nibble in the implementation above (also, I did not write this coldfusion this is courtesy of Ben Nadel).

Secondly, in PHP there is a SHA1 function for hashing... there is an argument to that function which is a boolean argument for "If the optional raw_output is set to TRUE, then the sha1 digest **is instead returned in raw binary format** **with a length of 20**, otherwise the returned value is a 40-character hexadecimal number." So my Coldfusion to mimic this is simply using the Hash() function and specifying it to use "SHA-1" and then converting that to binary... but how would I correctly limit it "to 20" in the same exact way PHP does?

I know this is involved by I have been stumped for quite some time now on these two issues... Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> using the Hash() function and
>   specifying it to use "SHA-1" and then converting that to binary... but
>   how would I correctly limit it "to 20"

You do not need to do anything. [SHA1 produces 160 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1). The binary result will always be 20 bytes, or 40 characters encoded as [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (two characters per byte).

```
  hashString = hash("Something wicked this way comes", "sha1");
  hashBinary = binaryDecode( hashString, "hex");
  writeOutput(" String / len("& len(hashString) &")");
  writeOutput(" Binary / arrayLen("& arrayLen(hashBinary) &")");
```

> 'H' which stands for "Hex string, high nibble first"
>   figure out to specify high nibble in the implementation above

Is there a specific reason you believe you must do something special/extra? From what I have read, the typical function used to generate hex in PHP, ie [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php), defaults to high nibble first, as does CF. Aside from the fact that CF converts the results to upper case, the results are identical.  Can you provide a specific example of where the PHP and CF results differ?

**PHP:**

```
echo bin2hex("Green Onions");
// result:  477265656e204f6e696f6e73
```

**CF**

```
writeDump( binaryEncode(charsetDecode("Green Onions", "utf-8"), "hex") );
// result: 477265656E204F6E696F6E73
```

Comment: This is great information! I really appreciate the response. I actually have one thing to clarify that I did not say in my original post... the unpack format is actually "H*" not "H" - any thoughts?

Comment: (Edit) I am not a php person, but the [pack docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) say * means "...repeating to the end of the input data". Sounds like it means apply it to the entire input string, not just a portion of it.  That is what binaryEncode/Decode do by default anyway. So again, it does not sound like you have to do anything. Not unless you have a specific example of the PHP code behaving differently than CF.

Comment: @BradMash - Regarding [your (now deleted) thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468449/weird-cfloop-file-behavior), glad you found a solution, but keep in mind S.O. threads are archived to benefit everyone :) Rather than deleting the thread, better to post the solution as an answer, so other folks can benefit from it as well.