# PHP's unpack in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, unpack

I need to convert this php function into a coldfusion function for an api and I'm not having much luck. I'm not familiar enough with php or a coldfusion unpack equivalent and have just hit a brick wall.

```
function i32hash($str) {
 $h = 0;
 foreach (unpack('C*', $str) as &$p) { $h = (37 * $h + $p) % 4294967296; }
 return ($h - 2147483648);
}
```

The end result should be i32hash('127.0.0.1:1935/vod/sample.mp4') = 565817233

this is the code I've been working with but its not working.  I get an error back of "Cannot convert the value 4.294967296E9 to an integer because it cannot fit inside an integer."  This happens at the modulus.

```
function i32hash(str) {
    var h = 0;

    // php unpack equivalent
    str = toBinary(toBase64(str));

    for(p in str) {
        h = (37 * h + p) % 4294967296;
    }

    return h-2147483648;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

**Updated answer, supplied by @Leigh in the comments below**

```
function i32hash(str) {
    var h = 0;
    var strArray = charsetDecode(arguments.str, "us-ascii");

    for(var p in strArray) {
        h = precisionEvaluate((37 * h + p));
        h = h.remainder( javacast("bigdecimal", 4294967296) );
    }

    return precisionEvaluate(h - 2147483648);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ColdFusion Equivalent to PHP Unpack and SHA1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978130/coldfusion-equivalent-to-php-unpack-and-sha1)

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? Because as written, it is very likely this question will be closed as [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or too broad.

Comment: I added some code to my original question @Leigh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a PHP guy, but my understanding is that `unpack('C*',..)` *should* translate to decoding the string using ascii encoding, ie `charsetDecode(theString, "us-ascii")`.

> I get an error back of "Cannot convert the value 4.294967296E9 to an
>   integer because it cannot fit inside an integer.

Unfortunately, CF's [modulus operator](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-expressions-and-number-signs/expressions-developing-guide.html), requires a 32 bit integer on the right side. The value 4294967296 exceeds the [maximum allowed for integers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fd2.html). You will need to use a [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead. The [PrecisionEvaluate()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/precisionevaluate.html) function returns a BigDecimal. Use it on the first half of the expression:

```
  firstPart = precisionEvaluate((37 * h + p));
```

Then obtain the modulus using the [BigDecimal.remainder()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#remainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) method instead:

```
  h = firstPart.remainder( javacast("bigdecimal", 4294967296) );
```

Finally, return the result:

```
   precisionEvaluate(h - 2147483648)
```

Comment: Thanks @Leigh.  That was exactly what I needed.  I went down the bigDecimal path but didn't realize the divisor must also be a bigDecimal.  I was also unaware that precisionEvaluate even existed.  ;)  Thanks again.  I appreciate your time.

For anyone just wanting the the unpack equivalent both of these work.
`charsetDecode(theString, "ascii") & toBinary(toBase64(theString))`

Comment: Glad I could help :) One thing to remember about precisionEvaluate: you must use it consistently to maintain the BigDecimal. As soon as you apply a mathematical operation on a BigDecimal variable *outside* that function, like `h  = h * 1`, instead of `h = precisionEvaluate(h * 1)`, CF will convert "h" back into a `java.lang.Double`. Ah, the joys of a (relatively) type-less language ;-)

Comment: Oops, just noticed a typo. The encoding should be [us-ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) - not "ascii". Answer updated.

Comment: @Leigh PHP pack/unpack functions would be good to add to CFLib (or github). I often see projects that don't have any CF code samples or third-party libraries, but they'll have PHP samples that make use of this PHP-specific function.

Comment: @JamesMoberg I'm not sure a 1 for 1 equivalent from the example above is worth a mention unless the function would include a format argument. That would be cool.  In this case, it turns out I was actually more hung up on the bigDecimal issue then I was the unpack.

Comment: rehhack - Yes, I think that's what James meant.  @JamesMoberg - Agreed, as I have to re-figure it out every time I use it. Still I have not figured out all the format options yet...